# Metaphor to describe a person who lacks charisma

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a good metaphor or idiom for a person who is completely uncharismatic. I'm preferably looking for a phrase that compares the person's charisma to something, such that it would fit the pattern "he had the charisma of **_**". For example, "he had the charisma of dry paint". The phrase would be used to describe a public figure in a satirical and slightly insulting manner.

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on the context. Should it be funny? Serious? Light-hearted? Insulting? Something else? You need to fit it into your context, which only you know.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Edited.

Comment: I think you really want a metaphor.

Comment: @DavidM Good point. Edited again.

Comment: Even with your edit, this is still completely dependent on the context, and I don't think it's a question we can answer. It depends entirely on your audience. A group of government officials will have a different definition of satire than a group of sailors. They'll also find different metaphors more effective. We can only tell you that blue and yellow make green, not how to paint a picture of grass.

Answer (score 2):

**[Cold fish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cold+fish)** a person who is very reserved or aloof in manner or who lacks normal cordiality, sympathy, or other feeling; an unemotional and unfriendly person;

Where charisma is a spiritual power or personal quality that gives an individual influence or authority over large numbers of people.

Answer (score 0):

He had the charisma of lawn clippings.

He had the charisma of a block of wood.  (John Kerry for example.)

He had the charisma of ... pretty much any inanimate object which is not particularly exciting.

... a log.
... broccoli.
... a potted plant. 
... etc.

You could get nastier:

... a soiled diaper.
... cow chips.
... a flat tire.
... cholera.
...  etc.

Answer (score 0):

***Similes:***

> - as charismatic as a slug
> - as charismatic as smegma
> - as charismatic as pond scum
> - as charismatic as tofu
> - as charismatic as vanilla ice cream without the vanilla
> - as charismatic as an afterbirth

***Metaphors:***

> - He was a giant yawn in the personality department.
> - She's a walking Sominex pill.
> - Jim's last name isn't Lambent, it's Somnolent!
> - In personality and charisma, Sally is a gaping yawn in a cave of boredom.
> - If you want to get Mr. Charisma's attention, just say, "Hey Morpheus, rise and shine!"
> - His charisma is the epitome of lobotomy.
> - Harold is a walking advertisement for the movie "The Living Dead."

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Oops! Call it a Freudian slip? I mean Sominex! I'll edit my answer, now. Thanks! Don